# Subject: Modifying Control Properties in ASP.NET Web Forms from a Separate C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Subject: Modifying Control Properties in ASP.NET Web Forms from a Separate C# Class

Body:

Hello everyone,

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms project using C#. I have a scenario where I need to modify the properties of a control, but I want to do this from a separate C# class file, not directly in the ASPX.CS file associated with the page.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this? I want to understand how I can access and modify control properties from a different C# class and have those changes reflected in the UI.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

WEB FORMS 1. LABEL 1 NO ES ACCESIBLE DEBIDO A SU NIVEL DE PROTECCION

Comment: What part of this is a C question?

Comment: ...why are you still using WebForms in 2023? And what is your organization's plan for dealing with the fact that all .NET versions released since .NET Core 1.0 have completely dropped support for it?

Comment: @Dai WebForms is part of the .NET Framework (which is part of Windows) and is supported for as long as the underlying Windows Server version is supported.  For e.g. Windows Server 2022 is supported for 10 years until 2032, so any WebForms apps running on Server 2022 is supported for security patches for that long, though no new features will be added. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Comment: Regarding the error message "LABEL 1 NO ES ACCESIBLE DEBIDO A SU NIVEL DE PROTECCION," it seems to be in Spanish and translates to "LABEL 1 IS NOT ACCESSIBLE DUE TO ITS PROTECTION LEVEL." Make sure that the control's protection level (probably the label in this case) is set to at least protected so that it can be accessed from other classes or the code-behind of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that each webform is really just a .NET class. So, in many ways you asking this question:

How can I modify values in a class with code outside of that class?

Well, like any code you write, then you need to call that external code from the first class instance. Or have the second class grab and get an instance of first class, and then once again that code is free to modify the control settings on that given web page class.

Since the page and controls are a standard .NET class, then how you approach this task is the same as how you would modify values in any class with external code. This approach is not limited then to web forms, but that of how you would modify values and properties of any class.

Often, I find using C# library code (static class code) works rather well, since often such code really doesn't benefit from being non static.

Either approach is fine.

Hence such code is free to modify values, and that includes controls and their settings and properties on that given web page.

So, say we have a web form with a DropDownList control.

However, over time it becomes rather repetitive to type the same code over and over to modify the properties of that dropdown list and supply that dropdown with data.

Example dropdown markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

So, now with external code in a static class, we can modify the properties of that dropdown.

This works fine:

```
    public static void LoadCbo(DropDownList cbo,
                               string strSQL,
                               string sDataField,
                               string sValueField)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                dt.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        cbo.DataTextField = sTextField; 
        cbo.DataValueField = sValueField;
        cbo.DataSource = dt;
        cbo.DataBind();
    }
```

So, now on page load event, I can modify the control settings and values of the drop-down list like this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            General.LoadCbo(cboHotels,
            "select ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName",
            "HotelName", "ID");
            
    }
```

So, the above external class code changes properties of the combo box (text and value columns), and sets the data source based on supplied SQL.

Nothing I can see here thus prevents one from using code outside of the current web page class to modify such values and controls.

Keep in mind the web page class lives for a very short time and goes out of scope rather fast at end of the page lifecycle.